# [drm:intel_enable_lvds]*ERROR* timed out waiting for panel to power on

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I get this error when I start mystem. 
I have been using a multi-boot system. Ubuntu, Win7, Arch.
I deleted everything, and try to install Arch, without susccess.

I just deleted the MBR with dd. Is there any association?
May be due to grub? Would syslinux be better?
Do I really need a bootloader, as I have only one OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need a bootloader.

You could try replacing your BIOS with openBIOS, which already contains a bootloader, so the boot becomes faster. But openBIOS may not be supported on your hardware, and you should not take the risk if you are not completely sure of what you're doing (recovery could become a nightmare).

EDIT: I have tried GRUB, GRUB2, Extlinux (Syslinux), and LILO. If you're looking for a simple and small bootloader, you should stick with LILO. It is very easy to setup and configure. Extlinux will make you spend too much unneeded time, and is bigger than LILO.